# Clicking the ads for solution of the game

Tags: android, admob, ads

I am new to android development and i have developed a puzzle game with about 50 levels. I know that users will hate my app if they stuck at a level for a long time. so i like to implement a strategy like - 'if you click on 2 ads from the ads below you will get the solution for that level'. can i do it. is it legal? i haven't saw any app using this strategy- why? is there any drawback in it? wont i make much money through this strategy? or is it impossible to implement this strategy through code or something?

Comment: It's probably legal, but this probably breaks the terms and services of AdMob and you'll get yourself banned if they find out. After all, this is not what advertisers pay AdMob for.

Comment: What you can do instead is implement an in-game currency with an Offer Wall (where advertisers pay you if your users try their product, watch a video, or fill out a survey, in exchange for a little bit of in-game currency). Here is a list of ad networks that support this particular Offer Wall scheme: http://www.mobyaffiliates.com/mobile-advertising-networks/?ad-formats=offerwall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is against the Admob publisher policies:

> Publishers may not ask others to click their ads or use deceptive implementation methods to obtain clicks. This includes, but is not limited to, offering compensation to users for viewing ads or performing searches, promising to raise money for third parties for such behavior or placing images next to individual ads.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly advise against it, while I couldn't find anywhere where admob explicitly mentions encouraging users to click on your ads, I know adsense has strict policies against encouraging users to click on ads and will ban you for life for these types of schemes.